# Adding SIP as a compiler for qmake

Tags: qt, makefile, pyqt, qmake, python-sip

I'm trying to integrate PyQt5 binding creation into my qmake build process, I have my SIP file ready and I've setup a compiler for it:

```
SIP_FILES += global/sip/Sy_version.sip

sipSourceBuilder.input = SIP_FILES
sipSourceBuilder.output_function = sipSourceHandler
sipSourceBuilder.variable_out = SOURCES
sipSourceBuilder.dependency_type = TYPE_C
sipSourceBuilder.CONFIG += target_predeps
sipSourceBuilder.commands = $$PYTHON $${PWD}/sipConfigure.py \
                                       $$QT_SIP_PATH \
                                       $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_} \
                                       $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/${QMAKE_FILE_IN}

QMAKE_CLEAN += $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/sipOutput/sip${QMAKE_TARGET}cmodule.cpp
SOURCES += $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/sipOutput/sip${QMAKE_TARGET}cmodule.cpp

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += sipSourceBuilder
```

The `defineReplace` function `sipSourceHandler` is working correctly.  When I start a build the `sipConfigure.py` script is not ran and an error occurs:

> make: *** No rule to make target
>   `../../Syren2/core/sipOutput/sipcoreSy_version.cpp', needed by`
>   /home/cmannett85/Programs/Syren2/libs/libcore.so.1.0.0'.  Stop.

Which makes sense if the script wasn't ran - but why wasn't it ran?  The Makefile shows the rule is there:

```
/home/cmannett85/workspace/Syren2/source/Syren2/core/sipOutput/sip${QMAKE_TARGET}Sy_version.cpp: ../../Syren2/core/global/Sy_version.h \
        /home/cmannett85/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/QtGlobal \
        // ...Lots of includes....
        ../../Syren2/core/global/sip/Sy_version.sip
    python3 /home/cmannett85/workspace/Syren2/source/Syren2/sipConfigure.py /usr/share/sip/PyQt5 /home/cmannett85/workspace/Syren2/source/Syren2/core /home/cmannett85/workspace/Syren2/source/Syren2/core/../../Syren2/core/global/sip/Sy_version.sip
```

(Sorry for the giant side scroll).  `${QMAKE_TARGET}` is `core` and it is declared as a variable in the Makefile.  I tried setting the `sipSourceBuilder.commands` to some randomly bashed in characters and nothing complained during the build, so it seems that `make` isn't even attempting to use `sipSourceBuilder`.  Any suggestions as to why?

Also I know that the SIP compiler also generates a header file that qmake should be made aware of, but I've commented that code out whilst I try to get this step going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was occurring due to make using string matching to link dependencies to targets, rather than detecting if a target/dependency is a path and doing any relevant conversion.  In my case, it was because the library dependency for my generated source file was listed as a relative path (`../../Syren2/core/sipOutput/sipcoreSy_version.cpp`), but the associated target was listed as an absolute path (`/home/cmannett85/workspace/Syren2/source/Syren2/core/sipOutput/sip${QMAKE_TARGET}Sy_version.cpp`).

The solution was to modify the `sipSourceHandler` output file name generator to return relative paths from the Makefile's location:

```
// SIP_SOURCE_ABS was previously returned, now SIP_SOURCE is.
SIP_SOURCE_ABS = $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/sipOutput/sip${QMAKE_TARGET}$${NO_PREFIX}.cpp
SIP_SOURCE = $$relative_path( $$SIP_SOURCE_ABS, $${OUT_PWD} )
```